# Why does my WiFi get continuously connected/disconnected?

Tags: wireless, 12.10

I have just installed Ubuntu 12.10 on my PC Lenovo B570e. I have WiFi connection in my room. It continuously connects and disconnects. What should I do?

Comment: Please provide results of  `sudo lshw -c network`, `rfkill list all` and `lsmod`

Answer (score 1):

If WMM is activated in your router, disable it.

When connecting to the console of your router with your browser you will find in the WLAN settings a conmboxbox to UNCHECK WMM.

WMM is Wi-Fi multi-media, a setting in modern WLAN routers you can switch on or off. It usually only causes trouble, at least in my experience, when switched on. (I had a similar problem and this solved it.)

Comment: what command is used to switch off wmm?